# Using Axios to get multi-dimensional array object in React-Native

Tags: react-native, multidimensional-array, axios

Good day

I am currently trying to learn React-Native through a Udemy course, but I am stuck at a stage where I need to get a multi-dimensional array from a source using Axios. Unfortunately, the end-point provided by the course is no longer available, but I recreated the data exactly as it was displayed in the course video. I then hosted the data in txt file on one of my own websites just so that I can continue with the course.

I am using VSCode for the coding and Android Studio for testing and debugging.

The problem now is that if I get the multi-dimensional array, it comes through just as a long string. If I flatten the array and remove the nested array, leaving me with a one dimensional array, then it pulls in the data as an array. So, it seems as if the problem is with the nested array.

This is the code that I am using to get the data:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import axios from "axios";

class CarList extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {carList:[] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://freedomsoftware.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/cars-file1.txt').then((response) =>{
                this.setState({carList: response.data});
           });
    }

    render () {
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            <View>
                {<Text>Car List</Text>}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default CarList;
```

The hosted txt file can be found here: https://freedomsoftware.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/cars-file1.txt

I know there is still a lot of code missing, such as error checking and so on, but this is just to get started and I assume I will still get to the error checking section in the course.

I have tried various changes to the file to see if it works, such as removing the "-", copying the array directly into the constructor and then fixing any syntax errors that VSCode points out and then copying it back into the txt file, but nothing seems to work. The moment I add the nested array, it comes through as a string instead as an object.

I also did try to contact the course instructor together with other students, but unfortunately there hasn't been any response from them.

I also did try to find solutions online and here on stackoverflow, but I just couldn't find something similar to this issue anywhere.

I am obviously missing something small or stupid that I just don't know about, but any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.